# SQL subquery sync and param

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have the following query and It doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    d1.*, iif(d1.PK = MIN(d2.PK), "Si", "No") 
FROM 
    demo AS d1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT d3.PK, d3.place, d3.date 
        FROM 
            demo AS d3 
        WHERE 
            d3.place=d1.place AND d3.date=d1.date AND d1.type="type1") AS d2 
ON 
    d2.place=d1.place AND d2.date=d1.date
```

The point is to mark with "Si" the first row in demo table with a concretly type and in the same place/date, other rows with the same values should be marked with "No". It seems that the subquery doesn't recognize de "d1" name to sync correctly, If I prove to change the "d1" valors to constants then There's a error about PK and an aggregate function that I don't understand.

Sorry If It's obvious but SQL is not my strongest point. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select d.*,
       iif(d.pk = (select min(d2.pk)
                   from demo as d2
                   where d2.place = d1.place and d2.date = d1.date and d2.type = "type1"),
          "Si", "No")
from demo as d;
```

Comment: Thaaanks, seems to work fine ^^

But maybe a little heavy to calculate. My PC doesn't respond during a few mins, I will try to optimize it :(

Comment: @Miluga . . . An index on `demo(place, date, type)` should help.

Comment: Well, a few mins in fact were about 9 hours. The index are created to (place, date) but I can't create it for type because this query works over another query that calculates the type (this one take only about 3 seconds to execute). I'm still stuck here... :(